# want to receive the data from Firebase Cloud Firestore that falls within the last 24 hours and is sorted in descending order based on a specific field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const currentTime = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();
const twentyFourHoursAgo = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
db.collection('product').where('Timestamp', '>',twentyFourHoursAgo).orderBy('Timestamp').orderBy('participantCount','desc').limit(5).get().then((결과) => {
```

So, I wrote the code like this, and while the request regarding the timestamp is working fine, the sorting based on the count is not being applied.

```
db.collection('product').where('Timestamp', '>', twentyFourHoursAgo).orderBy('Timestamp').orderBy('participantCount', 'desc').get().then((결과) => {}
```

Not OK. Filtering on timestamp seems to work, but
Descending sorting by count is not possible.

```
db.collection('product').where('Timestamp', '>', twentyFourHoursAgo).orderBy('Timestamp').get().then((결과) => {}
```

it’s OK

```
db.collection('product').orderBy('participantCount', 'desc').get().then((결과) => {}
```

it’s OK

The reason you want to do that is because you need .limit(5).
I don't think it's a problem to receive all of them and sort them, but there's no need to get a lot at once. This is because it tries to get additional data whenever it is needed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFvNp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO987.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.